# Return number of non-empty inputs in a table

Tags: jquery, input, html-table, row

Is there a way I can return the number of non-empty inputs in a table?

So far I have tried:

`$("#template_item_table").find('input:number[value=""]').length`

but it keeps giving me

`Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: number(…)`.

Here's my input:

`<input type="number" class="form-control quantity" name="quantity" min="1">`

Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-function) at this context

```
var len = $("#template_item_table").find('input[type=number]').filter(function(){
  return this.value.trim().length > 0;
}).length;

console.log(len + "non empty number text boxes are there!!");
```

to filter out the non empty number text boxes inside your table `#template_item_table`